# ajax request not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a controller with this code

```
  def index
    if params["destination"].present?
      @destination = params["destination"]
      @destination_name = params["destination_name"]
      @new_loc = (params["current_destination"].present? && (params["destination"] != params["current_destination"]))
......
......
          if (@new_loc == false) && params["city_areas"].present?
            city_area_ids = params["city_areas"].map(&:to_i)
            @hotels = @hotels.select{|ht| city_area_ids.include?( @booking_hotel_partner_details.select{|f| f.partner_booking_hotel_id==ht['id'].to_i}.first.booking_hotel.hotel_city_area_id ) }
          end   
end
```

hotels.index.html.haml

```
$('.checkbox-custom').on('change',function(){
    filter_home_stays();
    $('#searchForm').trigger('submit.rails');
});
```

hotels.index.js.erb

```
if (new_loc == "true") {
  $('#city-areas').children('ul.open-dropdown').remove();
  $('#city-areas').append('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'filter', :locals => ({:city_areas => @city_areas})) %>');
  $('#city_areas .local-amenities-drpdown').mCustomScrollbar({
    theme:"rounded-dark",
    mouseWheelPixels: 500,
  });
}
```

when click checkbox first time the filter works properly.
But after I change the destination it doesn't work
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Cna you try moving the escape javascript code inside double quotes  $('#city-areas').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'filter', :locals => ({:city_areas => @city_areas})) %>");

Comment: I have put that in js.erb file. Also that part is working fine. After the city areas have updated the city area filter ( checkbox dropdown) is not working

Comment: since you mentioned `But after I change the destination it doesn't work` its prolly `turbolinks`

Comment: what can I do for it then?

Comment: I am updating city areas using ajax. Also all other checkboxes are working fine.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Really stupid of me to not have understood such a simple thing.
What I did is changed my index,js.erb to update city area checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did.

```
if (new_loc == "true") {
  $('#city-areas').children('ul.open-dropdown').remove();
  $('#city-areas').append('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'filter', :locals => ({:city_areas => @city_areas})) %>');
  $('#city_areas .local-amenities-drpdown').mCustomScrollbar({
    theme:"rounded-dark",
    mouseWheelPixels: 500,
  });
  $('.city_area.checkbox-custom').on('change',function(){
    filter_home_stays();
    $('#searchForm').trigger('submit.rails');
  });   
}
```

Thanks guys for giving it a shout.You guys rock!